# Escaping "<<EOF" inside bash function definition

Tags: bash, git

I often use `git commit -F- <<EOF` in order to write an `EOF`-terminated string as a commit message.

Using

```
alias commitml="git commit -F- <<EOF"
```

Works as intended.

However I would like to be able to pass arguments.

So I wanted to define in my `.bashrc`:

```
commitml() {
   git commit $* -F- <<EOF
}
```

Which returns as an error when source()ing:

> bash: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file
> (wanted `EOF') bash: /home/yannick/.bashrc: line 8: syntax error:
> unexpected end of file

Is it possible to somewhat escape the `<<` so that it works just like in the alias?

Answer (score 4):

The EOF is evaluated when the function is defined; of course Bash is skipping the rest of the script until it finds the matching `EOF` terminator.

What you *seem* to be looking for is a way to consume standard input up through a particular token. The usual way to do that is to simply type your message and end it with a ctrl-D (or whatever your terminal is set up to use for signalling end of file).

```sh
commitml() {
   git commit "$@" -F-
}
```

You could use this like `commitml <<EOF` if you like, of course; or perhaps rename the function to `_commitml` and set

```sh
alias commitml='_commitml <<EOF'
```

This is one of the few valid uses of an alias over a function -- the text inside the single quotes only gets evaluated when you actually use the alias. Any tokens after `commitml` will get passed into `"$@"` (notice also the use of this properly quoted variable over the quoting-buggy `$*`).